# Cannot instantiate the type LinqMap

Tags: java

I've been a Java developer since 2011 and usually have no problem in getting the hang of the errors since I've seen them tons of times already. Even this one I've seen a lot and I usually know how to solve it.

However, today I ran into an odd problem which judging by what it means, I can't get my head around what the problem really is.

So I'm a modder, specificly for Minecraft and in this case Bukkit. However that is completly irrelevant for the problem since this is rather something to do with the language itself and not any library made with it.

So the error.

> Cannot instantiate the type LinqMap<Integer, ? extends ItemStack>

Usually when I see this, I think it's because the type I'm trying to use, either is an interface, is abstract, or the specified constructors are either private or not defined however some of these do have their own errors, but that's what I usually check.

I also noticed there's a lot of copies of this error over Stack Overflow, however most of them seem to point in the direction of instancing List which is an interface, or some custom class which is abstract. This would be the same, if it wasn't for the fact that I already checked this, and it's not the problem it turns out.

So the piece of code I originally tried to use, looks as follows

```
HashMap<Integer,? extends ItemStack> stackmap = new LinqMap<Integer,? extends ItemStack>(player.getInventory().all(prototype.getType()));
```

Now, this was a bit hard to spot, so I tried narrowing it down. I took note of the constructor of LinqMap which takes either no parameters, or a `Map<K,V>`.
Also want to point out that `all` returns `HashMap<Integer, ? extends ItemStack>` in case you wonder what it returns. Anyway, So I tried again with the following code

```
Map<Integer,? extends ItemStack> map = player.getInventory().all(prototype.getType());
HashMap<Integer,? extends ItemStack> stackmap = new LinqMap<Integer,? extends ItemStack>(map);
```

This still didn't work, so I tried using the empty constructor which ends up like this

```
HashMap<Integer,? extends ItemStack> stackmap = new LinqMap<Integer,? extends ItemStack>();
```

This still ended up in the error, which really surprised me, since the object is a class, it has no modifiers except being public, and both the constructors including the parameter-less one is empty.

So what's the problem here? Why can't I create an instance of a LinqMap when the code clearly allows for it?

Also, here's a small snippet of the class for reference, it's custom made by me and is a port of Linq from C# (not released)

```
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

public class LinqMap<K,V> extends HashMap<K,V> {

    /**
     * 
     */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1796259800183459223L;

    public LinqMap(final Map<K,V> other) {
        for (Map.Entry<K, V> item : other.entrySet()) {
            this.put(item.getKey(), item.getValue());
        }
    }

    public LinqMap() {
    }

    /* ... */

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Java, you're not allowed to instantiate wildcard types `?` directly.  If you're compiling with at least Java 7, then I recommend you simply take advantage of [diamond inference](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/language/type-inference-generic-instance-creation.html):

```
Map<Integer, ? extends ItemStack> map = player.getInventory().all(prototype.getType());

HashMap<Integer, ? extends ItemStack> stackmap = new LinqMap<>(map);
```

Comment: Thank you! This did the trick. I also wish I knew about diamond inference way earlier.